# How to reset html form values which are by default from value attribute

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I want to reset my html form. Using `<input type="reset">` it just only reset the values input which are filled just after the page loads but not the values specified by `value` attribute

I have tried following appoaches but it doesn't worked .

Watch my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4RrG3/) ( one approach is commented)

**HTML**

```
<form id="searchfrm">
   <input type="text" value="hiii">
   <input type="reset" class="rest">
</form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".rest").on("click", function(event){
      $('#searchfrm input').val('');
});

/*
$(".rest").on("click", function(event){
      $('#searchfrm input')[0].reset();
});
*/
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your expected behaviour here? Are you trying to clear all the fields, or reset them back to how they were when the page loaded?

Comment: @AdrianWragg I just want to reset my form input field to null or empty **when reset button is clicked**  that is in my example the value is "Hiii" i want it to reset to "" that is null.

Comment: Do you mean like ***[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RrG3/3/)*** ?

Comment: @ThinkDifferent the value in first input field ins still not reset through your code

Comment: Following on from the answers already provided, don't use `<input type="reset">` for this; that has a specific function that has been in common use for the last 20 years, which is different from the functionality you're requiring. Just use a normal button instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input type reset has some default behavior that must be prevented in order for your code to work. The reset input sets all inputs to the value attribute's value (attribute declared in HTML markup). This was overwriting the jQuery `.val()` functionality because the default behavior happens after the jQuery setting of the value.

```
$(".rest").on("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#searchfrm input').val('');
});
```

**Edit Further Explanation**

jQuery `.val()` behaves like `input.value`. This set the property.
jQuery `.attr()` behaves like `input.setAttribute()`.This sets the attribute.
Reset uses the value attribute of the Element not the the value property. For example the following code would also work.

```
$(".rest").on("click", function(){
    $('#searchfrm input').attr('value', '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to like this:

```
$(".rest").on("click", function(event){
   $('#searchfrm input[type="text"]').attr('value','');
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RrG3/4/)

Comment: @Anonymous You meant like this?